# Extract value from json in Python

Tags: python, json

I am extracting the value input from string using python.

```
{"eventid":"cowrie.command.input","input":"cd /dev/shm; cat .s || cp /bin/echo .s; /bin/busybox KUHJY","message":"CMD: cd /dev/shm; cat .s || cp /bin/echo .s; /bin/busybox KUHJY","sensor":"cowrieHoneypot2","timestamp":"2021-05-06T00:20:09.535217Z","src_ip":"76.250.199.133","session":"e3e61e8606ed"}
{"eventid":"cowrie.command.input","input":"tftp; wget; /bin/busybox KUHJY","message":"CMD: tftp; wget; /bin/busybox KUHJY","sensor":"cowrieHoneypot2","timestamp":"2021-05-06T00:20:09.729719Z","src_ip":"76.250.199.133","session":"e3e61e8606ed"}
```

Now, what regex should I use as in one string the value of the input is:

```
cd /dev/shm; cat .s || cp /bin/echo .s; /bin/busybox KUHJY
```

Whereas, the value of the input in the next string is:

```
tftp; wget; /bin/busybox KUHJY
```

So, how can I simply extract the value of Input? Some sample strings are given in this [file](https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/c2806baa-08df-462d-b764-de7a96365caf).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This really seems like more of a problem of parsing your JSON content than using regex:

```py
import json

text = '{"eventid":"cowrie.command.input","input":"cd /dev/shm; cat .s || cp /bin/echo .s; /bin/busybox KUHJY","message":"CMD: cd /dev/shm; cat .s || cp /bin/echo .s; /bin/busybox KUHJY","sensor":"cowrieHoneypot2","timestamp":"2021-05-06T00:20:09.535217Z","src_ip":"76.250.199.133","session":"e3e61e8606ed"}'
json = json.loads(text)
inp = json["input"]
print(inp)
```

This prints:

```
cd /dev/shm; cat .s || cp /bin/echo .s; /bin/busybox KUHJY
```

Comment: how to load the whole file and read it and store the result in another file?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what the entire file looks like, l probably can't give anything more than I have done above, but basically you may load the top level JSON text once using `json.loads`, then parse it as appropriate.

Comment: You can use this [file](https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/2bfd5c68-f27c-4ee9-b33a-4af9302b12f2) it contains few lines from the original file. If regex can be used then that's a good thing.